# comparing Algorithm complexity of two algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Before i ask this question here, I found that this site is the appropriate site to ask this question [from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se.)

I am having 2 algorithms Say A and B for same problem.

```
A is complexity is = 5nlogn
B is complexity is = n sqrt(n)
```

I want to find the value of n0 so that i can prove A is better than B.

**I tried the below:**

```
5nlogn/nsqrt(n) = 5logn / sqrt(n)

by putting 
 n = 512  ==> i got the answer. But i am not sure whether it is correct?
```

How can i do that?.

**To be clear:** i want to prove the below

A = BigO(B)

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do, can you explain further? What does n0 represent?

Comment: You gave the complexities. What about the constants?

Comment: @MohitJain 5 is a constant

Comment: @MohitJain.Please see the updated post. To be clear: i want to prove the below

A = BigO(B)

Comment: @codebox .Please see the updated post. To be clear: i want to prove the below A = BigO(B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly.

You are looking for

```
5nlog(n) < nsqrt(n)
5nlog(n) / nsqrt(n) < 1
5log(n) / sqrt(n) < 1
```

From [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5log_2%28n%29+%2F+sqrt%28n%29+%3C+1), this is correct for all `n > ~3500`

---

As a side note, if you want to show `5nlog(n)` is in `O(nsqrt(n))`, you can tweak the constants, and add a constant C:

```
5nlog(n) < C*nsqrt(n) for all n > n0
```

When choosing `C=10`, the above holds for all `n>0`

Comment: Thank you the reply, But did you use base 2 for Log ?

Comment: Thank amit, But i am not sure, What base should i use. When i use base10 i am getting different answer. :( So What must be the correct answer, Say if i have no = 512, 1024, 2048 and 4932

Comment: @Backtrack I am not following the question, are you asking for which `n0\in {512,1024,2048, 4932}` the equations `5nlog(n) < nsqrt(n), n>n0` hold? The answer to this question is 4932, if that's what you're asking. If you are looking for lowest such `n0`, that's depend on the base you are using - and you need to ask your TA which base to use (or if you got the complexity from some algorithm, find it yourself)

Comment: Can you please help me in this, I wan to pick the best n0 value, I tried with base10 and base2

Comment: Why the answer is 4932, So you are saying that we should use log base 2. Is my understanding correct

Comment: You can't say what the base is unless you know the algorithm, but it is most likely 2. For example, a binary tree search is `log2`, a trinary tree search is `log3` (but few people use trinary trees). The question also only makes sense if the coefficients for the two algorithms are equal, which they typically won't be. For example, lets say you have an O(N) algorithm and O(N^2) algorithm. If each step takes 10 seconds for both, O(N) is better for every N>1. But if it takes only 1s for the latter (while still costing 10s for the former), then the point of equilibrium changes.